# Is there's a way to shut down window with php?

Tags: php

I want to shut my window down using PHP, but I haven't found any good resource. I wonder if there is a way to do that in PHP.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it doesn't have any access to client windows. You need to do that with JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean can you close a browser window in PHP? Not without generating some JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. But no.

```
echo '<script>window.close();</script>';
```

Please, just please don't take this too seriously. PHP is a server side language. Which means it has no access to your browser itself. You should try using JavaScript if you have the chance.

Resources to close the window using JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close